# How to convert factor to date object in YearMonth format

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have factor data as follows in dateData:

> Factor w/ 24 levels "Apr 2017","Apr 2018",..: 11 3 23 21 19 5 9 7 15 1 ...

I am converting factor data into Date object as follow:

```
dateData1 <- as.Date(dateData, format = "%y%m")
```

I want factor data into YearMonth format

but its returning **NA** like

`[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA`

Comment: use `as.character(dateData)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information

Comment: also if you want a year-month variable, you might want to look at `as.yaermon` from the `zoo`-package

Comment: I have tried this but Actually I want dateData for subset() function as I am taking Year and Month  input from user so I get specific data from my data 
set after subset

Comment: I also tried as.yearmon but it is converting into year only

Comment: The format for dates in the form `Apr 2017` should be `"%b %Y"` - look at `?strptime`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you can use either yearmon from the zoo package or as.Date:

```
dateData <- factor(c("Apr 2017", "Apr 2018"))
as.Date(paste(as.character(dateData), "01"),format = "%B %Y %d")
require(zoo)
as.yearmon(as.character(dateData))
```

Comment: `as.yearmon` has a `"factor"` method so the last line could be just: `as.yearmon(dateData)` .

Answer (score 0):

Or in base-R

```
dateData <- factor(c("Apr 2017","Apr 2018"))
dateData2 <- factor(format(as.Date(paste0("01 ",as.character(dateData)),
                        format="%d %b %Y"),format="%y%m"))
```